frame-benchmarking-0.35.0: use of undeclared crate or module `alloc`
I am trying to upgrade the base-parachain to v1.13.0 and got an issue with the frame-benchmarking. This error coming from the frame-benchmarking crate which throws an error
 error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `alloc`
      --> /Users/chungquantin/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/frame-benchmarking-35.0.0/src/v1.rs:1738:2
       |
  1738 | /     sp_runtime::format_runtime_string!(
  1739 | |         "\n* Pallet: {}\n\
  1740 | |         * Benchmark: {}\n\
  1741 | |         * Components: {:?}\n\
  ...    |
  1750 | |         error_message,
  1751 | |     )
       | |_____^ use of undeclared crate or module `alloc`
       |
       = note: this error originates in the macro `sp_runtime::format_runtime_string` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

